# Error: xxx Object is not callable. ¿Qué significa y cómo lo soluciono?

Tags: python

Tengo este programa

```
a = 5
print("valor=", 5*a())
```

que al ejecutar me arroja este error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/candid/PycharmProjects/scrapper2/scrapper.py", line 2, in <module>
    print("valor=", 5*a())
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

y no entiendo que estoy haciendo mal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Explicación corta: Usa `[]` para acceder a un elemento de una colección. Usa `()` para llamar a una función.

En Python, un objeto `X` cualquiera es *callable* cuando puede ser usado como una llamada a función `X()`, posiblemente recibiendo parámetros y retornando algo.

Una variable numérica no es *callable*. No es algo que esté definido; no hay un código que ejecutar detrás de ese valor.

Tampoco son *callable* las cadenas, listas, tuplas y diccionarios, por la misma razón.

Normalmente este error se presenta cuando se usan `()` en lugar de `[]` para acceder a un elemento dentro de una cadena, lista, tupla o diccionario.

Los siguientes usos son correctos (con `[]`):

```
nombre = "Jacinto Perez"
lista = ["azul", "rojo"]
tupla = ("pollo", "gato")
dic = {"Mac": 1, "PC": 2}

print(nombre[2])
print(lista[1])
print(tupla[0])
print(dic["Mac"])
```

produce

```
c
rojo
pollo
1
```

Pero si cambias los `[]` por `()`

```
print(nombre(2))
print(lista(1))
print(tupla(0))
print(dic("Mac"))
```

arroja error:

```
  File "/home/candid/PycharmProjects/scrapper2/scrapper.py", line 6, in <module>
    print(nombre(2))
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

**¿Qué objetos son *callable*?**

Son *callable* las funciones, generadores y cualquier objeto que defina el método mágico `__call__`.

Ejemplo: tenemos una clase `Cliente`, que almacena nombre y saldo:

```
class Cliente:
    def __init__(self, nombre, saldo):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.saldo = saldo
```

podemos crear un cliente con

```
cliente = Cliente("Jacinto Perez", 1000)
```

pero no podemos decir

```
print(cliente())
```

pues aparece el error

```
TypeError: 'Cliente' object is not callable
```

que dice que la clase `Cliente`no es *callable*, y por tanto ningún objeto de esa clase lo es.

Para convertirlo en *callable*, definimos el método `__call__`, con la siguiente *firma*

```
def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
```

Notese que siempre hay que definirla con esos argumentos, incluso si no se ocupan en una implementación en particular. De no ser así, Python no considera *callable* la clase.

¿Qué se supone que debe hacer este método? Cualquier cosa que sea apropiada a nuestra aplicación; por ejemplo, en una aplicación bancaria el método más usado puede ser la consulta de saldo del cliente:

Entonces, redefinimos la clase `Cliente`:

```
class Cliente:
    def __init__(self, nombre, saldo):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.saldo = saldo

    def __call__(self, self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.saldo


cliente = Cliente("Jacinto Perez", "jperez@hotmail.com", "912341234")
print(cliente())
```

ahora imprime el saldo del cliente.

Nota: este ejemplo normalmente se resuelve definiendo una función de consulta

```
def saldo(self):
    return self.saldo
```

pero, que va! hay que poner un ejemplo simple.

Implementar `__call__` es más asunto de conveniencia cuando hay un método en particular que ocupas frecuentemente y quieres ahorrarte tener que escribir el nombre del método una y otra vez.

**¿Cómo saber si un objeto es *callable*?**

Existe la función `callable(objeto)` que retorna `True` si el objeto es *callable* y `False` en otro caso:

```
saldo = 1000
nom = "Jacinto"
cliente = Cliente(nom, saldo)

callable(saldo) # Retorna False
callable(nom) # Retorna False
callable(cliente) # Retorna True
```